# List of objects to List of Lists in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `List` of objects, say
`List<MyObject> = new List<MyObject>{object1, object2, ..., object10}`

Each object has property "Property1" which is a dictionary with different number of keys for each object, where for each key, the value is again a dictionary but here the value for each key is a `string`. I would like to convert this `List<object>` to `List<List<string>>`, so for each object I want to create a list with string values, where values are taken from this nested dictionary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it's this:

```
yourList.Select(mo => mo.Property1.SelectMany(d => d.Value.Values).ToList()).ToList();
```

It produces a **List**<*List*<string>> - i'll use bold and italic to distinguish:

- `yourList.Select` produces the enuemration that will become the **List**, so there is one entry in the **List** for every entry in the list of `MyObject`
- `mo.Property1.SelectMany` enumerates the outer dictionary of `Property1`, getting the `Value.Values` for each entry in the outer dictionary.

  - Each outer entry's `Value` is the inner `Dictionary<...,string>` and hence is a Dictionary with a `Values` collection that is a bunch of strings. `Value.Values` thus represents a collection of strings associated with each outer dictionary entry
  - Fed with these multiple "collection of strings" `SelectMany` collapses them into a single enumeration of strings, that is converted the a list with ToList, thus the `.ToList()` on `SelectMany()` gives you the *List*
- The `.ToList()` at the end of the expression gives you the **List**< ... >

Answer (score 0):

The fast way to map it again:

```
var newList = new List<List<string>>();
    foreach(var item in items){
        newList.Add(item.Property1.Values.ToList<string>());
    }
```